# Generate CRUD code against LINQ datasource

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, crud

I have a rather large database exposed to my application using LINQ-to-SQL.  I need to generate the boilerplate CRUD code and would rather not write it by hand.  Other than CodeSmith's PLINQ, is there something that would just generate that code from he DBML file? (the interfaces would be a bonus - but just the code for now).  I'd prefer something that would not embed itself into my VS project - I just the code generated.

Thanks and Happy Holidays!

Comment: So, you mean, LINQ-to-SQL? It's not the same thing as LINQ you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont think there is a ready made soultion to create inetrfaces and entity objects for CRUD from Dbml file.

you could consider to use [T4 Templates](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=t4+templates&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a)